# Record the sound of a program to the microphone

Tags: linux, audio, shell, microphone, pulse-audio

I want to record the sound of a program and to direct it as an microphone entry on linux.

For instance, I'm listening a music on youtube, and I want that music to be send to my skype's conversation instead of my voice.

Last but not least, I know how to do it using pavucontrol, I have to go to "Recording" and to switch the "Record stream from", but I want to do the exact same thing from the command line, and not using a gui.

I tried pactl load-module module-loopback source=1 sink=2 (where 1 is my desktop sound, 2 is Analog Stereo Duplex (but it also includes the normal sound on top of my input....) and it doesn't work as expected. I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226955/7552

Comment: I'm maximizing my chances of getting an answer, because my question is compatible with those two sites. I Also asked on Ubuntu forums, and pulseaudio IRC. No answer. Thanks for your constructive comment.